# Would LMS-specific tags be appropriate (Moodle in particular)?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I use Moodle at my institution. I often struggle to find online support to get Moodle to do interesting things. Moodle has a pretty decent forum, but (like almost every other help forum out there), it pales by StackExchange standards. I've often thought that it would be great if there were a StackExchange just for Moodle. However, that might be overkill.

A simpler solution, I think, would be simply creating a "moodle" tag on Academia SE. Academia SE probably has the largest collection of Moodle users who understand the SE culture of asking and answering questions, so I think this would make a lot of sense. When last I checked, in fact, there were over 50 questions on Academia SE that mention "Moodle".

I came close to doing this when I created a more generic "learning-management-system" tag (with "lms" as a synonym) for a Moodle-specific question: [How do you send personalized information to each student in Moodle?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/108859/how-do-you-send-personalized-information-to-each-student-in-moodle?noredirect=1#comment284899_108859), but someone recommended that I ask here at Meta before I create such a specific tag. So, here's my question: **would LMS-specific tags be appropriate for Academia SE (e.g. "moodle", "blackboard", "canvas", etc.), or would they be too specific?**

As a related side note, StackOverflow has a "moodle" tag for programming-related questions; I am thinking of configuration questions finding a home here at Academia SE.

Comment: A [tag:blackboard] tag would be too easily confused (with, you know, the things that you write on with chalk).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, "blackboard-lms" should remove any possible confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, I like the idea of having a “LMS” tag, because it unifies several different related sets of items into a single category. Learning management systems are becoming increasingly important, and having a tag to search for them may help users find useful related content, even if it's not specific to their platform.

Comment: By "such a tag", do you mean the "learning-management-system" tag or the "moodle" tag, or both?

Comment: LMS. Individual systems can be searched for directly.

Comment: should we also have lms as a tag, made a synomym of the full name? It seems to be a commonly used abbreviation.

Comment: It wouldn’t hurt.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I've already created the "learning-management-system" tag, but I don't have the points to create the "lms" synonym. Could you or someone with sufficient points please create that synonym?

Comment: Please avoid using abbreviations as tag titles. They're completely opaque to people who don't know them. (And, to me, "LMS" is the London Mathematical Society.)

Comment: The tag is learning-management-system, but lms should point to it, since people may know of lms, but not know the full meaning.